# Mouse "jumps" while holding a mousebutton

Tags: 13.10, mouse, trackpad

i am very new to Ubuntu (13.10). I've just installed it yesterday and have some problems with my mouse. While holding a mousebutton it jumps all over the screen but holding a"mousebutton" using the trackpad ( sorry i forgot to mention that i am on a laptop) i don't have any problems and everything works fine and smooth.

I checked the controll but there is no option that might fix my problem.

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an hardware problem, given how a quick Google search gives me some results of more people complaining about this problem, both on Linux and Windows alike. Some solutions include:

- Try another mouse. Your mouse may be faulty and be suffering from some internal interference. You can test if it's your mouse fault my testing it in other PCs/Operating Systems.
- Shiny desk. Your mouse may not like your desk's surface and just by pressing a button, it giggles enough to take a jump.

Comment: hm. my external mouse works fine. my onboard touchpad still doesn't.
Advanced Silicon S.A. SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad     thisis my touchpad. still can't understand why it works fine if I don't use thetouchpad buttons but a double click on the pad for "holding a mousebutton"